# Is it possible to use a DLL for editor extension in release mode?

Tags: c#, dll, unity-game-engine

I am working on an editor extension. I have some time consuming algorithms and factored them out to a separate project and make it to the extension as a DLL and use it in the extension project. The algorithms are not dependent on Unity and DLL has no reference to Unity. On the other hand I created a windows form application and set its target framework to `unity 3.5 .net full` and call the DLL's methods from it. When I set to RELEASE mode for The DLL project and standalone project and run it, I get significantly better performance (sometimes 2X) than the unity extension running on Unity.

- Does unity editor always run DLLs in debug mode?
- If so, Is there a way to tell JIT compiler to optimize and disable debugging for just a specific DLL?

**EDIT:** After more examination with the project here are my findings. Using the DLL inside:

- a standalone **.NET** project is very fast because of better CLR. Takes **1100ms** to complete.
- a standalone PC unity game (.exe) takes **2100ms** to complete.
- an editor extension is slower. Takes **2700ms**.